# how to set Eclipse workspace to specific folder by default

Tags: 16.04, eclipse

I am running ubuntu 16.04. I am installing eclipse using a bash script. I am able to install eclipse successfully. 
Now I have my project stored in some folder, which I want somehow to be able to display in eclipse workspace. 
So when I start eclipse, it shows my project into workspace. It can be done when reboot occurs or some bash script to do it permanently.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse stores it's UI preferences in [`<eclipse_home>/eclipse/configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/IRC_FAQ#Where_are_Eclipse_preferences_stored.3F). The parameters in that file are described in the online documentation (for Luna) [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2Fide%2FIDE.Preferences.html) But basically you need to set three parameters:

```
RECENT_WORKSPACES=/your/workspace/location
SHOW_RECENT_WORKSPACES=false
SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG=false
```

Setting the bottom two parameters to false causes Eclipse to automatically load the first workspace from the RECENT_WORKSPACES value.

Comment: I tried to do this. I am getting error. 

An error has occurred. See the log file
/home/techy/workspace/.metadata/.log

Comment: Can I create link between Eclipse workspace and my desired folder of project using bash script ?

Comment: please show content of your `org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs` file. I don't understand your question, a workspace is by definition a folder, but one in which Eclipse has placed relevant metadata in to identify the containing projects.

Comment: My question is simple. I just want to see my project stored at /Documents into workspace but not as a copy. So when I open eclipse, in the workspace I see my project. If I make any changes to it, then the corresponding changes will be made to /Documents/project

Comment: What I searched, it looks the easy way is to create link between /Desktop/workspace and /Documents/project.